# Loading any MVC page fails with the error "An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I am having an intermittent issue that is appearing on one server only, and is causing all MVC pages to fail to load with the error "An item with the same key has already been added."

Restarting the application pool fixes the issue, but until then, loading any mvc page throws the following exception:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 10/11/2012 08:09:24 
Event time (UTC): 10/11/2012 08:09:24 
Event ID: d76264aedc4241d4bce9247692510466 
Event sequence: 6407 
Event occurrence: 30 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/21/ROOT-2-129969647741292058 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: d:\websites\SiteAndAppPoolName\ 
    Machine name: UKSERVER 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6156 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\SiteAndAppPoolName 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: ArgumentException 
    Exception message: An item with the same key has already been added.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.WebConfigScopeDictionary.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.WebConfigScopeDictionary.TryGetValue(Object key, Object& value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.ScopeGet[TValue](IDictionary`2 scope, String name, TValue defaultValue)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.ScopeCache.Get(IDictionary`2 scope, HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.GetClientValidationEnabled(IDictionary`2 scope, HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.FormHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Dashboard_Functions_BookingQuickLookup_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Websites\SiteAndAppPoolName\Views\Dashboard\Functions\BookingQuickLookup.cshtml:line 3
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Dashboard_Functions_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Websites\SiteAndAppPoolName\Views\Dashboard\Functions.cshtml:line 5
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Dashboard_Index_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Websites\SiteAndAppPoolName\Views\Dashboard\Index.cshtml:line 9
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://SiteAndAppPoolName.spawtz.com/Dashboard 
    Request path: /Dashboard 
    User host address: 86.164.135.41 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\SiteAndAppPoolName 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 17 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\SiteAndAppPoolName 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.WebConfigScopeDictionary.TryGetValue(Object key, Object& value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.ScopeGet[TValue](IDictionary`2 scope, String name, TValue defaultValue)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.ScopeCache.Get(IDictionary`2 scope, HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.GetClientValidationEnabled(IDictionary`2 scope, HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.FormHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Dashboard_Functions_BookingQuickLookup_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Websites\SiteAndAppPoolName\Views\Dashboard\Functions\BookingQuickLookup.cshtml:line 3
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Dashboard_Functions_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Websites\SiteAndAppPoolName\Views\Dashboard\Functions.cshtml:line 5
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Dashboard_Index_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Websites\SiteAndAppPoolName\Views\Dashboard\Index.cshtml:line 9
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details:
```

As mentioned, it's every MVC action that throws this error until the app pool is restarted, and the error seems to be occurring in `System.Web.WebPages.Scope.WebConfigScopeDictionary.TryGetValue(Object key, Object& value)`

Has anyone seen this issue before?  It's only happening on this server, on any of the app pools on the server (not confined to this one) and an app pool restart sorts it.

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers,

Matthew

**EDIT:**

Here is the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <section name="listManagers" type="Spawtz.ListManagersConfigSection, SpawtzConfiguration" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="cs" />
  </appSettings>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <to value="spawtzerror@spawtz.com" />
      <from value="matthew@spawtz.com" />
      <subject value="Error in SiteAndAppPoolName Spawtz Application" />
      <smtpHost value="127.0.0.1" />
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <lossy value="true" />
      <evaluator type="log4net.spi.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="WARN" />
      </evaluator>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="User: %X{User} %n%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n%n%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
    </root>
    <logger name="Error">
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
  <system.web>
    <!--  DYNAMIC DEBUG COMPILATION
          Set compilation debug="true" to enable ASPX debugging.  Otherwise, setting this value to
          false will improve runtime performance of this application. 
          Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging symbols (.pdb information)
          into the compiled page. Because this creates a larger file that executes
          more slowly, you should set this value to true only when debugging and to
          false at all other times. For more information, refer to the documentation about
          debugging ASP.NET files.
    -->
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--  CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGES
          Set customErrors mode="On" or "RemoteOnly" to enable custom error messages, "Off" to disable. 
          Add <error> tags for each of the errors you want to handle.

          "On" Always display custom (friendly) messages.
          "Off" Always display detailed ASP.NET error information.
          "RemoteOnly" Display custom (friendly) messages only to users not running 
           on the local Web server. This setting is recommended for security purposes, so 
           that you do not display application detail information to remote clients.
    -->
    <!--<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" />-->
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <!--  AUTHENTICATION 
          This section sets the authentication policies of the application. Possible modes are "Windows", 
          "Forms", "Passport" and "None"

          "None" No authentication is performed. 
          "Windows" IIS performs authentication (Basic, Digest, or Integrated Windows) according to 
           its settings for the application. Anonymous access must be disabled in IIS. 
          "Forms" You provide a custom form (Web page) for users to enter their credentials, and then 
           you authenticate them in your application. A user credential token is stored in a cookie.
          "Passport" Authentication is performed via a centralized authentication service provided
           by Microsoft that offers a single logon and core profile services for member sites.
    -->
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <!--  AUTHORIZATION 
          This section sets the authorization policies of the application. You can allow or deny access
          to application resources by user or role. Wildcards: "*" mean everyone, "?" means anonymous 
          (unauthenticated) users.
    -->
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <!-- Allow all users -->
      <!--  <allow     users="[comma separated list of users]"
                             roles="[comma separated list of roles]"/>
                  <deny      users="[comma separated list of users]"
                             roles="[comma separated list of roles]"/>
            -->
    </authorization>
    <!--  APPLICATION-LEVEL TRACE LOGGING
          Application-level tracing enables trace log output for every page within an application. 
          Set trace enabled="true" to enable application trace logging.  If pageOutput="true", the
          trace information will be displayed at the bottom of each page.  Otherwise, you can view the 
          application trace log by browsing the "trace.axd" page from your web application
          root. 
    -->
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <!--  SESSION STATE SETTINGS
          By default ASP.NET uses cookies to identify which requests belong to a particular session. 
          If cookies are not available, a session can be tracked by adding a session identifier to the URL. 
          To disable cookies, set sessionState cookieless="true".
    -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <!--  GLOBALIZATION
          This section sets the globalization settings of the application. 
    -->
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
        <add namespace="SpawtzController.ViewModels" />
        <add namespace="SpawtzController" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="/Views/*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="FixIIS5xWildcardMapping" type="Elmah.FixIIS5xWildcardMappingModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MvcContrib" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.34.0" newVersion="2.0.34.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.1.0" newVersion="2.5.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Windsor" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.1.0" newVersion="2.5.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Spawtz" connectionString="cs" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Spawtz" applicationName="SiteAndAppPoolName" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
    <errorFilter>
      <test>
        <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
      </test>
    </errorFilter>
  </elmah>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
      <remove name="ErrorLog" />
      <remove name="ErrorMail" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
      <remove name="elmah" />
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="/Views/*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
      <add name="Mvc" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" />
      <add name="elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
        <remove value="index.html" />
        <remove value="index.htm" />
        <remove value="Default.asp" />
        <remove value="Default.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT AGAIN:**

Ok, since it seems there's no easy answer to the above question, perhaps there is an answer to this one: Can I somehow configure IIS to automatically recycle the app pool after encountering a specified number of errors within a specified period of time?  I know I could enable rapid fail protection, but that's not what I'm after, as then I would have to manually restart the app pool.  As a workaround (read: hack...) I want to fix it so it restarts itself if it gets a load of errors in a row.  Is that doable instead?

**ONE MORE EDIT**

Ok, this error occurred on another server this morning too, so seems it's not just the server config that is causing it.  Perhaps it's something in my code, but I'm stumped as to how to go about diagnosing it, as I can't replicate it and can't debug into it...  Seems I have some more investigating to do.

Comment: Could you show your webconfig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We struggled with this issue for 7 months. The issue seemed to come about when our IIS application pools were automatically recycled. Recycling them again or flicking the web.config usually brought the site back online but it took a lot of digging to find the root cause.
After assistance from some external consultants and Microsoft tech support, the issue was traced to a bug in the Telerik library where a key is dynamically added to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings without muti-thread race condition protection. In this instance, we were able to bypass the offending code by adding some entries to the web.config. The issue was identified by Telerik several versions ago so we will update to a newer version for a more permanent fix.
The problem comes about if you dynamically update the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings. MS suggestion is as follows:

Change this:

```
try
{
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourAppSettingsKey"] = string1;
}
catch(System.Exception)
{
}
```

to this:

```
if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key) == null)
{
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
        if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key) == null)   // check required inside the lock()
        {
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Steve.  We are also using the Telerik library, so it might well be caused by that.  I will investigate further and let you know, and given that you're the only one to have suggested a response for this issue, I'm going to mark this as the answer here.  Thanks again.

Comment: Do you know which version caused the error and when it was resolved?
What settings did you  have to change/set?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested, I've solved this (I think) in a very hacky kind of way...  What I've done is wire up to the `Application_Error` event in global.asax, and then check to see if the `Server.GetLastError()` exception (or its inner exception) contains the details of the error that is thrown (see full stack trace in the question).  If it does, I then call for an app domain restart using the method found in this article: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Oct/08/Recycling-an-ASPNET-Application-from-within (basically using `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();` or if that doesn't work by touching the web.config file.

I need a shower...