# All MVC pages fail with the message an item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Ultimately I am trying to address the same issue that is referenced in [Loading any MVC page fails with the error “An item with the same key has already been added.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321205/loading-any-mvc-page-fails-with-the-error-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already) and [An item with the same key has already been added](http://forums.asp.net/t/1843922.aspx/1?+An+item+with+the+same+key+has+already+been+added+exception+thrown+fixed+by+recycling+app+pool). A duplicate of the first link is [All MVC pages fail with the message an item with the same key has already been added](http://dotnetforum.net/topic/62125-all-mvc-pages-fail-with-the-message-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added) but it has some additional pertinent information, confirming that it only effects MVC pages, while webforms and other aspects of the application that deal with appSettings continue to work without error.

I have now seen this four times in production and it has not been seen in any other environment (dev, test, UAT). I have closely examined and debugged through the source code of System.Web.WebPages and the relevant sections of the MVC stack but did not run into anything that stood out.  This problem has persisted through a migration from MVC3 to MVC4, and the latest changeset from aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com does not appear to address this issue.

A quick summary of the issue:

- Every MVC page is affected and completely unusable
- WebForms and other aspects of the application that use appSettings continue to work just fine
- Only an appPool restart will correct this issue
- At least once and as referenced in an article above, this has happened after a regular time interval recycle of the appPool by IIS
- This has happened during both low and high volume traffic periods
- This has happened on multiple production servers, but the issue only affects a single server at any given time, as other servers continue serving MVC pages

The offending line of code is `var items = new Lazy<Dictionary<object, object>>(() => appSettings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => (object)appSettings[key], comparer));`, but it occurs when the lazy initialization is forced by requesting a value from `items`  The appSettings variable is from System.Web.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings which is a direct static reference to System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings. So I beleive the line is equivalent to: `var items = new Lazy<Dictionary<object, object>>(() => System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => (object)appSettings[key], comparer));`

I rarely suspect framework issues, but it appears that appSettings has two distinct keys that are the same (not the same as a NameValueCollection supporting multiple values for the same key).  The `comparer` being used in the MVC stack is the StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase which appears to match what is used by the configuration system. If this is a framework issue, the MVC stack appears to be very unforgiving when it forces the NameValueColleciton into a dictionary using the `ToDictionary()` extension method.  I believe using `appSettings.AllKeys.Distinct().ToDictionary(...)` would probably allow the MVC stack to operate normally as the rest of the application does and be oblivious to the possibility of duplicate keys. This unforgiving nature appears to also contribute to the issue described in [NullReferenceException in WebConfigScopeDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577735/nullreferenceexception-in-webconfigscopedictionary)

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.WebConfigScopeDictionary.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.WebConfigScopeDictionary.TryGetValue(Object key, Object& value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.ScopeGet[TValue](IDictionary`2 scope, String name, TValue defaultValue)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.ScopeCache..ctor(IDictionary`2 scope)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.ScopeCache.Get(IDictionary`2 scope, HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.GetClientValidationEnabled(IDictionary`2 scope, HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.FormHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at ASP._Page_Areas_Client_Views_Equipment_Index_cshtml.Execute()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

To separate my question from the questions already asked, I will ask has anyone seen the configuration system be corrupted with multiple duplicate keys or where a NameValueCollection.AllKeys returns two identical keys? I know you can have multiple keys defined in the config file, but the last key wins, and that scenario does not reproduce this issue.

Although I am not alone in seeing this behavior multiple times, there are relatively few posts describing this issue, so I also suspect that it might be a configuration/environmental issue, but again, servers will run for months without experiencing this issue, and an appPool restart immediately corrects the problem.

I have mitigated this issue by forcing an appPool restart if a server starts seeing this error, but management is not happy about this "hacky" solution because some user will still experience an error.

Help?!?!?

EDIT:

Here is a contrived, cheezy test that can reproduce the scenario, but doesn't help in solving the issue.  It happens during approx. 20% of the test runs. The code will blow up for other threading reasons, but it is the "Same key has already been added" error that is of interest.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    readonly NameValueCollection _nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
    private Lazy<Dictionary<object, object>> _items;

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReproduceSameKeyHasAlreadyBeenAdded()
    {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            ThreadStart threadStart = AddEntry;
            Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
            threads[i] = thread;
        }
        foreach (var thread in threads)
            thread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        _items = new Lazy<Dictionary<object, object>>(() => _nameValueCollection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => (object)_nameValueCollection[key], ScopeStorageComparer.Instance));

        object value;
        _items.Value.TryGetValue("4", out value); // approx. 20% of time, blows up here with mentioned error
        Assert.IsTrue(value != null);
    }

    private int _counter;
    private void AddEntry()
    {
        _counter++;
        try
        { // add a bunch of even keys, every other one a duplicate
            _nameValueCollection.Add((_counter%2) == 0 ? _counter.ToString() : (_counter + 1).ToString(), "some value");
        }
        catch {}
    }
}


StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
       at UnitTestProject1.ReproduceSameKeyHasAlreadyBeenAdded.<TestMethod1>b__0() in c:\Git\AspNetWebStack\aspnetwebstack\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 37
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
```

Comment: This is a **wild guess**, but if settings somehow through some code path change at runtime, I wonder if it's not threadsafe and might result in some race condition where the same key exists twice.  I wouldn't think you'd have code modifying settings at runtime though.

Comment: @AaronLS - I have thoroughly examined the codebase for anything that might modify the appSettings and have not found anything.  I have looked for instances of trying to update a setting using ConfigurationManager, adding a setting through reflection or writing directly to the web.config file. Thanks for making a guess, I'm open to any ideas...

Comment: When you use distinct, does it solve the problem?

Comment: @RodJohnson - I have no way of reproducing the problem.  We have 4 servers in our production environment and we have seen this happen 4 times in 8 months.  It always only affects a single server at any one time, so it is fairly rare. We have not seen this in any other environment (dev/test/UAT) and I haven't had any success trying to reproduce this through integration/unit tests. I took the "hacky" solution to mitigate the problem and we are not running the modified MVC assemblies.

Comment: What are you passing in for comparer?

Comment: Shouldn't it be Dictionary<string, object> ?

    new Lazy<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                        () => appsettings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => (object) appsettings[key], comparer));

Comment: @RodJohnson - The comparer is the 'ScopeStorageComparer', which is a wrapper around 'System.StringComparer' and 'System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>'. As long as the 'key' and 'value' is a string, it will use the 'StringComparer' when evaluating equality. As far as it being a Dictionary<string,object>, I don't think it matters, but I have confirmed the MVC code is using 'Lazy<Dictionary<object, object>>'. As Mirko suggests below, I will try some threaded tests using both dictionary types and see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. 
Please refer to my response here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17415830/2423407][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17415830/2423407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We came across this same issue and finally tracked it down to dynamic updating of the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings collection. I have posted a full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415830/2423407

Comment: Thank you Steve.  Although I haven't fully investigated whether this is definitely our issue, but we are using an older version of Telerik controls and there has been no other reasonable answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely positive the error is occurring on the line where you are initializing items and not the line on which items is being used to add to some other dictionary (Static I would presume).

To me the most likely way this would occur is if the code was executed in parallel (by two concurrent users) and the second one executing causing the exception.

As a general workaround I usually initialize a strongly typed class with all configuration parameters as an [auto-start provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) (and add some strongly-typed type checking of the values as well, such as checking that an int is an int, etc) to avoid run-time errors.

This has the double benefit of loading these at warmup, not when the users want the info (better response performance) and thread-safety is supposedly guaranteed with them as well.

See if that doesn't fix your issue. If you do not want to do that I would at the very least try to execute the code that is failing for you with multiple threats hitting it, as my guess would be that you will see your error occur fairly reliably.

Comment: Absolutely positive? No, but pretty close. The issue seems to be happening inside the System.Configuration assembly, which uses a NameValueCollection for appSettings. Because it happens deep inside the configuration system, I'm not sure how to apply your workaround.  I have reviewed the System.Configuration code and it appears to handle concurrency, but I haven't eliminated all possibilities. Because the NameValueCollection is not thread safe, I can reproduce this with a contrived test and the stack trace mimics what we see above. I will post the code and stacktrace in another post.